# Can Apache Camel File component use Java WatchService?

Tags: apache-camel, java-7

Is it possible to configure Apache Camel File component to use Java 7 `WatchService` rather than scan input directory periodically?

If no, is it possible to achieve the same goal (i.e. avoid file system scans when nothing changed) with Camel "easily"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated to remove wrong info*

You can write such a component, maybe by extending the File component.

Or even simpler, build something very simple with the ´WatchService´ that fires of a trigger message to the File component when there is a file to pick up. Then you just have to worry about the file logic, which works rather well with Camel.

Something like:

```
from("mywatchcomponent:/var/files/")
 .to("direct:pickUp")

from("direct:pickUp")
 .pollEnrich("file:/var/files/")
 .bean(whatever)..
```

Comment: Does it (the first sentence) mean that Java 7 is not supported by Camel? Or only that Java 7's new features are not being leveraged?

Comment: My bad, I'm a bit behind.. Camel 2.10.0+ does actually and officially support Java 7.

There is no built in support for Java 7 features since Camel should also run on JRE6. Updated my answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution sketch, i'm going to accept your answer. Btw. as i already stated in another comment: requirement to run on JRE6 does not limit the possibility to use Java 7 features when run on JRE7.

Answer (score 0):

Camel is [currently](http://camel.apache.org/what-are-the-dependencies.html) built to run on Java 6. 
But you could probably write your [own implementation](http://camel.apache.org/creating-a-new-camel-component.html) or ask this new feature on [Apache-Camel issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL).

Comment: Well, but is this technically possible to write Java software that is capable of using Java 7 features when run on Java 7? Thanks for the pointers anyway!

Comment: No, java code is written and compiled to use a specific version. It is possible to run Java 6 code (retro compatibility) on Java 7 JVM but not the opposite as some of the features (e.g. WatchService) would be unknown.

Comment: Well, it is enough to use reflection to access J7 API (though better, <100% reflection, approaches probably exist). You are right that the code should be compiled with "java 6 compatibility", i.e. with java class file version <= 50.